# angular foreach Json and repeat

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, foreach

I'm pretty new to angular and I'm stuck with something.
I'm pulling data from an API with a service I named RateInfoService.
The JSON looks like this

[image]

```
  $scope.refreshData = function() { 
     RateInfoService.getMarket($scope.alarmingMarket).success(function(data) {
      if($scope.alarmingMarket.length <= 1){
         $scope.rate = [];
         $scope.rate.marketid = data.query.results.rate.id;
         $scope.rate.rate = data.query.results.rate.Rate;
         $scope.rate.updateTime = data.query.results.rate.Time;
         console.log($scope.rate);
  } else {
    angular.forEach(data.query.results.rate, function (value, key){
      $scope.rate = [];
      $scope.rate.marketid = data.query.results.rate[key].id;
      $scope.rate.rate = data.query.results.rate[key].Rate;
      $scope.rate.updateTime = data.query.results.rate[key].Time;
      console.log($scope.rate);
    });
   }
 })
}
```

and checking array length is only because I pull another URL as API.
I try to show it in the view but it fails, because the user can fill in chips.. but after it also cola. The view only shows cola because it overwrites the chips because of the loop. 
I tried in both different ways

```
<tr ng-repeat="rate in rates track by $index">
   <p>{{rate.marketid}} {{rate.rate}}</p>
   <p>Last price update {{rate.updateTime}} </p>
</tr>
```

and

```
<tr ng-repeat="data.query.results.rate.id track by $index">
   <p>{{$index + 1}}</p>
   <p>{{rate.marketid}} {{rate.rate}}</p>
   <p>Last price update {{rate.updateTime}} </p>
</tr>
```

Both only show cola. It is probably because of scope.rate = [] but I struggle with my code and how to fix it. with PHP I often used someting like `foreach($prices as $index=>pricing){code}`

But how can I do it with angular, or does anyone has a fix or example code.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop you are just replacing the previous value with the latest one, so you end up with only the last value which is COLA.

You need to add all the array to an array.
You could simply do it like so

```
$scope.rates = data.query.results.rate
```

Now you have an array identical to the response from the API.
To loop through this

```
<tr ng-repeat="rate in rates">
    <td>{{rate.id}} - {{rate.rate}}</td>
    <td>Last price update {{rate.date}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: angular.forEach($scope.rate = data.query.results.rate, function (value, key) ... Is kinda same as <tr ng-repeat="data.query.results.rate track by $index"> Where I tried to do the same in the view

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment. Is there a problem?

Comment: Don't worry, it's solved. I will post the solution later on !

Answer (score 1):

I think you are initializing the array multiple times. So just pull that array declaration from for loop to the outside. So it should work Fine..

```
$scope.rate = []; // Pull this out of for Loop Like Below

$scope.refreshData = function() { 
    //Intialise Here
    $scope.rate = [];
     RateInfoService.getMarket($scope.alarmingMarket).success(function(data) {
      if($scope.alarmingMarket.length <= 1){
         $scope.rate = [];
         $scope.rate.marketid = data.query.results.rate.id;
         $scope.rate.rate = data.query.results.rate.Rate;
         $scope.rate.updateTime = data.query.results.rate.Time;
         console.log($scope.rate);
  } else {
    angular.forEach(data.query.results.rate, function (value, key){
      //Instead of Here
      $scope.rate.marketid = data.query.results.rate[key].id;
      $scope.rate.rate = data.query.results.rate[key].Rate;
      $scope.rate.updateTime = data.query.results.rate[key].Time;
      console.log($scope.rate);
    });
   }
 })
}
```

Comment: I have tried this before. Sadly I didn't solve the problem. The same result happens

Answer (score 1):

> The answer is very simple you done one mistack my friend

you are creating **$scope.rate = []** in for loop so every time it will go in loop it will empty your array so in for loop **last value** will be inserted in your array and your loop stop so you got only **cola**

**UPDATE:**

---

see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/bcfzrfn9/1/

And if you use table for ng-repate then only tr not working you have to use td inside it see in my example i created two table first on display nothing but second one is working.

> NOTE: Dont create object again pass your data in scope and use
>   directly in ng-repate example: $scope.dataObject = your object

see in example.

```
<table>
        <tr ng-repeat="dataObject in data.results.rate">
            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td>ID : {{dataObject.id}} - RATE: {{dataObject.Rate}}</td>
            <td>Last price update {{dataObject.Time}}</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I do understand that offcourse. I just don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @Romano see i updated answer let me know if you want any thing  not you can edit ng-repate as you want